# Struggling with a nested if function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

Struggling with this nested if. I just want it to return the true condition if any of the three are found in the cell (Jan, Feb or Mar returns "Q1", etc.). Right now it's just return 0 for whatever I have in the cell... Do I need to use OR?

`=IF(D2 ="Jan,Feb,Mar", "Q1", IF(D2="Apr,May,Jun", "Q2", IF(D2="Jul,Aug,Sep", "Q3", IF(D2="Oct,Nov,Dec", "Q4",0))))`

Comment: Is D2 a date formatted as `mmm` or is a string that has `Jan`?

Comment: It's formatted as a String like Jan, Feb, Mar

Comment: In a *single cell* do you have literally "Jan,Feb,Mar"?  Or could it be any of the three, individually?  If it's the latter, `=If(or(D2="Jan",D2="Feb",D2="Mar"),"Q1",...`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. I only have ONE instance of the 3 letter string. Just one word. Might be just Jan, might be just Aug, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
="Q" & INT((MONTH(--(D2 & " 1, 2017"))-1)/3)+1
```

Comment: Wow... very simple and concise. Thanks a bunch!